# Get all the zipcodes within any district or cities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm

What I want is an API that will give all the list of zip codes based on city/district name. Is there any API (Free or paid) available which can fulfill my requirement.

I want to build the following components in react.

1. The user first selects the country.
2. Then users select states within the country.
3. After state selection, another dropdown shows list of cities/districts within that state.
4. and finally the fourth dropdown which shows all the zip codes within that city.

I got npm packages for the country, states, and cities dropdown but I unable to find any API or npm packages for the zipcodes. Please suggest any API of npm-package.

Comment: did my answer help Pranay? how are you getting on ?

Comment: Yes, the first link matches my requirement thanks.

Comment: glad it helped mate. have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do either of these help you?

https://www.zipcodeapi.com/ or https://postcodes.io/